# Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http"}} when trying to use thorntail

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, thorntail

I am trying to run a rest service using thorntail and maven, and in it i need to use the java.net.http httpClient and process the result. But i am getting those errors when i am trying to run it.

I know thorntail is outdated and no longer supported but not using it is not really an option for me at that point.

```
2021-05-04 18:25:16,353 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) THORN0013: Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          io.thorntail:undertow:2.7.0.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:16,374 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) THORN0013: Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          io.thorntail:logging:2.7.0.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:16,374 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) THORN0013: Installed fraction:                   JAX-RS - STABLE          io.thorntail:jaxrs:2.7.0.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:16,375 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) THORN0013: Installed fraction:                  Elytron - STABLE          io.thorntail:elytron:2.7.0.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:19,311 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:19,323 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:19,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Thorntail 2.7.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) starting
2021-05-04 18:25:19,680 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (MSC service thread 1-2) THORN0019: Install MSC service for command line args: []
2021-05-04 18:25:20,378 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.10.4.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:20,712 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2021-05-04 18:25:20,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2021-05-04 18:25:20,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:20,741 INFO  [org.xnio] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) XNIO version 3.7.3.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:20,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2021-05-04 18:25:20,791 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.3.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:20,844 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 24 core threads with 192 task threads based on your 12 available processors
2021-05-04 18:25:20,847 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.1.3.Final starting
2021-05-04 18:25:20,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.11.2.Final
2021-05-04 18:25:20,961 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2021-05-04 18:25:21,034 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
2021-05-04 18:25:21,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2021-05-04 18:25:21,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Thorntail 2.7.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started in 1919ms - Started 99 of 105 services (22 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2021-05-04 18:25:21,630 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer] (main) deploying film.war
2021-05-04 18:25:21,674 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "film.war" (runtime-name: "film.war")
2021-05-04 18:25:22,522 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.film.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.film.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.film.war
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:116)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:299)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:283)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:93)
    ... 8 more

2021-05-04 18:25:22,529 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "film.war")) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.film.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.film.war
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http"}}
2021-05-04 18:25:22,530 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "film.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.film.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.film.war
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http"}}
2021-05-04 18:25:22,543 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment film.war (runtime-name: film.war) in 11ms
2021-05-04 18:25:22,547 ERROR [stderr] (main) org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.film.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.film.war
2021-05-04 18:25:22,547 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http"}}
2021-05-04 18:25:22,547 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,548 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,548 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,548 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,548 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:476)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,549 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:747)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,549 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,549 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,549 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,550 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,550 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:57)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,550 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:134)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,550 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:87)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,551 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.film.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.film.war
2021-05-04 18:25:22,551 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http"}}
2021-05-04 18:25:22,551 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,552 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 12 more
2021-05-04 18:25:22,555 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
2021-05-04 18:25:22,559 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8080
2021-05-04 18:25:22,570 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.1.3.Final stopping
2021-05-04 18:25:22,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0050: Thorntail 2.7.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) stopped in 35ms
2021-05-04 18:25:22,716 ERROR [stderr] (main) org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.film.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.film.war
2021-05-04 18:25:22,716 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http"}}
2021-05-04 18:25:22,716 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,717 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,717 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,717 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,718 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:476)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,718 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:747)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,718 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,719 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,719 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,719 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,720 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:57)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,720 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:134)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,721 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:87)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,721 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.film.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.film.war
2021-05-04 18:25:22,721 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.net.http"}}
2021-05-04 18:25:22,721 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,722 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 12 more
2021-05-04 18:25:22,722 ERROR [stderr] (main) java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
2021-05-04 18:25:22,722 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:669)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,723 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:309)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,723 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,723 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,723 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.JarFileResourceLoader.getJarEntry(JarFileResourceLoader.java:187)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,724 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.JarFileResourceLoader.getClassSpec(JarFileResourceLoader.java:130)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,724 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:330)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,724 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,725 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,725 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,725 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,725 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,726 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,726 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.stop(Swarm.java:438)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,726 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.tryToStopAfterStartupError(Swarm.java:779)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,727 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:756)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,727 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,727 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,727 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,728 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,728 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:57)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,728 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:134)
2021-05-04 18:25:22,729 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:87)
```

the call to httpCLient is like this:

```
package api.model;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TMDB_Caller {

    //variables
    private String apiKey;
    private int pageSize = 20;

    
    //connstracteur---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public TMDB_Caller(String apiKey) {
        super();
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }
    
    ///////////     Genres      /////////////

    //listAllGenres_uri-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String listAllGenres_uri() {
        //https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=3aacfef6a62a872d2a4717b9b6cd5283&language=en-US
        return "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key="+apiKey+"&language=en-US";
    }
    
//getAllGenres()----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public List<Genre> getAllGenres() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String uri = listAllGenres_uri();
        
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
              .uri(URI.create(uri))
              .build();
        
        HttpResponse<Supplier<AllGenresBody>> response = client.send(request, new JsonBodyHandler<>(AllGenresBody.class));
        Supplier<AllGenresBody> allGenres_result = response.body();
        
        String genres_str = allGenres_result.get().genres.toPrettyString();
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Genre> genreList = mapper.readValue(genres_str, new TypeReference<List<Genre>>() {});
        
        return genreList;
    }

}
```

the pom.xml file of the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>api</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>api</groupId>
  <artifactId>film</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>film</name>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

    <version.thorntail>2.7.0.Final</version.thorntail>

    <skip-docker-build>false</skip-docker-build>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
        <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.json</groupId>
       <artifactId>json</artifactId>
       <version>20210307</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
        
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.json</groupId>
       <artifactId>json</artifactId>
       <version>20210307</version>
     </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

the pom of the parent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>api</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>api</groupId>
    <artifactId>user</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>user</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <version.thorntail>2.7.0.Final</version.thorntail>

        <skip-docker-build>false</skip-docker-build>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.2.20</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
                <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.thorntail}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                 <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>1.2.1</version>
                 <configuration>
                         <mainClass>api.model.App</mainClass>
                 </configuration>
         </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

the "solution" that was often on the net was to add a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to WEB-INF the containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="java.net.http"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

but that did not solve the problem, I have found early advice for when the java.net.http was still in incubator stage but that did not fix it either.

The question I have, I guess, is how do i fix this? Nothing i have found on the net really worked/applied to my situation.

Is there some more additional info i need to provide?

Comment: The solution you found online, with adding `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, is the right thing to do. It's also documented in https://thorntail.io/posts/announcing-thorntail-2-4-0-final/ Note that the documentation says "This file must be placed in the `WEB-INF` directory in your WAR", so it speaks about the _target_ structure. It doesn't say where it should be in the source tree. I believe the correct location is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` -- do you use that? If that doesn't help -- can you create a minimal but complete reproducer somewhere on GitHub?

Comment: Ladicek I aldready did add it, before asking the question, did not fix the problem,

Comment: I am fairly new to github, what would be the best way to share a repo?

Answer (score 2):

Well a colleague of mine found the answer, turns out you need to tell maven where the web ressources are so i added:

```
       <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                    <directory>$/film/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                                    <includes>
                                            <include>**/jboss-deployment-structure.xml</include>
                                     </includes>
                            </resource>
                    </webResources>
            </configuration>
```

after the :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin
                </artifactId>
</plugin>
```

part of the pom  and that fixed it. Inspired by this answer: [Filtering Maven files into WEB-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782352/filtering-maven-files-into-web-inf)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the root cause was:
I used an old xml configuration file of `JBoss version 7.2` for the new `JBoss version 7.4`